# Lebesgue outer measure satisfies $\lambda^{*}([a,b]) \leq b-a$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

*Aaagain*, I fail to understand the trivial:

Using compactness argument it is straightforward to show: 
$$\lambda^{*}([a,b]) \geq b-a$$
And everything is OK.

But, regarding $\lambda^{*}([a,b]) \leq b-a$, Cohn says:

> For any closed bounded interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ it is easy to see that $\lambda^{*}([a,b]) \leq b-a$ (cover $[a,b]$
>   with sequences of open intervals in which the first interval is barely larger than
>   $[a,b]$, and the sum of the lengths of the other intervals is very small).

From this hint I *should* be able to arrive at $\lambda^{*}([a,b]) < b-a + \epsilon$, for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$, but I don't understand how..

Help?

Comment: So what's the question? $\geq$ or $\leq$?

Comment: @user2345215 the question is about $\lambda^{*}([a,b]) \leq b-a$ using what Cohn suggested.

Comment: Everything you may wish for is in this question and the comments below: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174517/on-lebesgue-outer-measure-of-an-interval

Comment: @LordSoth Thank you! You think I should delete this question?

Comment: @Dror I think deleting a question is not a good idea, we can mark it as duplicate though.

Comment: I always thought that $\lambda^\ast([a,b]) = b-a$.

Comment: @Integral sarcasm..?

Comment: Im being honest! Im a little dumb in measure theory.

Comment: @Integral I'd say that makes two of us, but I'm not going to, because "dumb" isn't it. Try "still clueless" :-).

Comment: I'm not sure what's your exact definition of outer measure, but if it's something like infimum of sum of lengths of covering intervals with length defined as b-a, then doesn't it follow from the covering by that exact interval (or almost exact if it can't be closed)?

Comment: @user2345215 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure

Comment: @Dror: Why don't you cover it by $(a-\frac\varepsilon2,b+\frac\varepsilon2)$ with length $b-a+\varepsilon$ then?

Comment: @user2345215 It needs to be covered by an infinite sequence of open intervals

Comment: @Dror: Empty interval is open. (and if you can't use that - that's an arbitrary restriction, I wouldn't want a definition which disallows it, that's just plain stupid). Nevertheless, I'll post the answer with nonempty intervals as well.

Comment: @user2345215 calm down.. And perhaps think twice before you call something "stupid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to cover your your interval $[a,b]$ with just $1$ interval $(a-\frac\varepsilon2,b+\frac\varepsilon2)$ of length $b-a+\varepsilon.$ That's why it's trivial.

If you definition is needlessly restrictive and requires infinitely many open intervals, set empty sets for the remaining intervals.

If your definition of an interval is needlessly restrictive, you can cover your set like this
$$\left(a-\frac\varepsilon4,b+\frac\varepsilon4\right)\cup\bigcup_{n=3}^\infty\left(-\frac\varepsilon{2^n},\frac\varepsilon{2^n}\right)$$
of total length $b-a+\frac\varepsilon2+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac\varepsilon{2^n}=b-a+\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=b-a+\varepsilon$.

Maybe now you see why is it stupid to not allow what I suggest.

Comment: Thanks. But note that It's not *my* definition, and I will not call It stupid, because I do not yet know if these restrictions are in fact useful or not. My ""guess"" is that they *are* useful.