# n-rectangle has no content zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A set $R\subset\mathbb R^n$ with the form $[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]$ where $a_i<b_i\ \forall i=1,\dots,n$ is called a $n$-rectangle, with volume $|R|=(b_1-a_1)\cdots(b_n-a_n)$.

A set $D\subset\mathbb R^n$ is of $\textbf{content zero}$ if $\ \forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists\ n$-rectangles $R_1,\dots,R_m$ such that

$$D\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^mR_i\ \text{ and } \ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m|R_i|<\varepsilon.$$

Show that any $n$-rectangle is not a set of content zero.

My attempt is to consider $\varepsilon=|R|$, then there exists $n$-rectangles $R_1,\dots,R_m$ such that $|R_1|+\dots+|R_m|<|R|$ and $R\subseteq R_1\cup\cdots\cup R_m$. This implies $|R|\leq\big|R_1\cup\cdots\cup R_m\big|$.

Now the problem is to show that $\big|R_1\cup\cdots\cup R_m\big|\leq|R_1|+\cdots+|R_m|$ which is a contradiction.

Any idea ?

Comment: Show that if $R\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^mR_i$ then $|R|\leq \sum_{i=1}^m|R_i|$ (each $R,R_i$ being an $n$-rectangle). This is intuitive, but can be tricky to prove…

Comment: can you give me a hint on this tricky fact ?

Comment: the $n$-dimensional case is just extra notation, so focus on $n=1$ first. In this case, each $R_i$ is an interval (and you may without loss of generality assume $R_i\subset R$ by replacing $R_i$ with $R_i\cap R$). Now, collect all the endpoints of the $R_i$’s; this forms a partition of $R$. For example, if $R=[0,10]$ and $R_1=[0,7]$ and $R_2=[3,10]$, then we have the partition $P=\{0,3,7,10\}$ of $R$. Now, a little bit of thought will give you the desired inequality (think back to this example, or a few other examples to see how to convert intuition into a formal proof).

Comment: So here is my thought. Consider the 1d-case. Suppose $R=[a,b]\subseteq R_1\cup\cdots\cup R_m,\ R_i=[a_i,b_i]$.  Assume without loss of generality that $R_1$ is the first rectangle of the cover from the left side. Let \begin{align} S_1&=R_1=[a_1,b_1] \\ S_2&=[b_1,b_1+b_2-a_2] \\ S_i&=\left[\sum_1^{i-1}b_i-\sum_2^{i-1}a_i\ ,\ \sum_1^ib_i-\sum_2^ia_i\right]   \end{align}
Then $|S_i|=|R_i|=b_i-a_i$, and $R_1\cup\cdots\cup R_m=[\min a_i,\max b_i]\subseteq S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_m$ 
Hence, $\big|R_1\cup\cdots\cup R_m\big|\leq\big|S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_m\big|=|S_1|+\cdots+|S_m|=|R_1|+\cdots+|R_m|$

Comment: But doing this way, I feel something seems not rigorous. That is $R_1\cup\cdots\cup R_m\subseteq S_1\cup\cdots\cup S_m$, to have this we need to show that $\max b_i \leq\sum\limits_1^mb_i-\sum\limits_2^ma_i$, which is not simple. 
Then, I need to generalize into n-dimensional case, which I feel not quite clear.

Comment: Whatever the $a_i,b_i$ are, rename all of them and arrange them in increasing order, $a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_p=b$ (where $R=[a,b]$). Then, $|R|=b-a=\sum_{j=1}^p(t_j-t_{j-1})\leq\cdots$. If you’re still in doubt, look up the corresponding integration chapters of Spivak/Munkres.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way to show this is to show that for any covering of a rectangle $D$ by rectangles $R_k$, we have $|D| \le \sum_k |R_k|$.

The proof is tedious & long winded, but straightforward. The idea is to first trim the $R_k$ so that they are all contained in $D$, then split $D$ into many sub rectangles, each of which is contained in at least one of the $R_k$.

Call two rectangles $R,R'$  **overlapping** **iff** they an interior point. I will call a set of the form $\prod_k [a_k,b_k]$ where at least one of the pairs $a-k,b_k$ satisfies $a_k=b_k$ a **flat** rectangle.

Note that if $ D \subset \cup_k R_k$ then $ D \subset \cup_k (R_k \cap D)$. We can discard any $R_i$ if $R_i \cap D = \emptyset$. However, it is possible that $R_i \cap D$ is a flat rectangle. It is straightforward to show that if $R_i$ is a flat rectangle, then $D \subset \cup_{k\neq i} (R_k \cap D)$. Repeating shows that with $R_k' = D \cap R_k$ and $K$ being the set of non empty non flat $R_k$ we have
$D \subset \cup_{k \in K} R_k' \subset \cup_k R_k$. We also note that
$|R_k'| \le |R_k|$ for each $k \in K$, so it is sufficient to show that
$|D| \le  \sum_{k \in K} |R_k'|$.

So, we can assume that $R_k \subset D$ to simplify subsequent notation.

If we have a rectangle $R= \prod_k [a_k,b_k]$ and we 'split' one of the sides (with $m_k \in (a_k, b_k)$) into $[a_k,b_k] = [a_k, m_k] \cup [m_k, b_k]$ to create two non overlapping rectangles $R_1,R_2$, and we see that $|R| = |R_1|+|R_2|$. Hence we can split a rectangle into many parts one side at a time and the sum of the volumes remains constant.

Now collect all the $a_1,b_1$s of each rectangle into a set $P_1$, and similarly for the other sides to get $P_2,..,P_n$. The $P_i$ form a partition of each side of $D$, and using the technique of the preceding paragraph, we can refine $D$ into a collection of rectangles $D_k$ such that $D = \cup_k D_k$ where $|D| = \sum_k |D_k|$ and each $D_k$ is completely contained in at least one of the $R_j$.

Let $I$ be a subset of indices such that $D_k \in \cup_{i \in I} R_i$ for each $k$, then we have
$|D| = \sum_k |D_k| \le \sum_{i \in I} |R_k| \le \sum_k |R_k|$. In particular,
$D$ is not of content zero.

Comment: At first, I tried to prove this strightly since I thought it seemed quite simple. But then, I realized it’s more complicated than intuition.  
So, I tried finding another way which is more simple. And I found 2 way to prove this. The first way is to show that every set is of content zero has empty interior. The other is to show that if a set is of content zero then it has zero volume. And I completed the proof of the second way, but the first way still struggling me

Comment: What part is complicated?

Comment: You are mentioning the straight proof of mine ? So I simply suppose $R$ is of content 0 and  consider $\varepsilon=|R|$. 
I intend to show that $\big|R_1\cup\cdots\cup R_m\big|\leq|R_1|+\cdots+|R_m|$. This is the complicated part for me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The volume is only defined for a rectangle, and $R_1 \cup R_2$ need not be a rectangle.

Comment: you’re right. I need to add the definition of volume of a set by integral on this problem. Then, how do we prove that inequality?

Comment: Well, I think proving that an open set has volume is about the same amount of work as proving the above.

Comment: Can I solve the problem this way : since R is n-closed rectangle, it is compact, hence there exists some finite cover of n-rectangle. This means there exixst $\varepsilon$ such that $|R_1|+…+|R_m|\leq\varepsilon$, a contradiction

Comment: @PermQi What does $|R_1|+... \le \epsilon$ contradict?

Comment: Is negation of definition is "$\exists\varepsilon>0:\ \forall I$ finite and $\forall n-$rectangles $\{R_i\}_I,\ \sum\limits_I \big|R_i\big|\geq\varepsilon$ or $D\not\subseteq\bigcup\limits_I R_i$" ?

Comment: I do not follow your approach.

Comment: My idea is before proving $R$ is not of content 0, then I must write carefully what is “$R$ has no content 0”. So I write that statement out, but I’m not sure if my nagative statement is true

Comment: You need to show that there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all coverings that $\sum_k |R_k| \ge \epsilon$. As I mentioned earlier I think this is essentially the same difficulty as showing $|D| \le \sum_k |R_k|$.

Comment: @PermQi: See the mathoverflow questions [Elementary proof that an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ does not have measure zero?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/389151/15780) and [Open sets do not have measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63030/13130). For useful insight into why this result is not trivial, see [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/51555/15780) by [Timothy Gowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timothy_Gowers) (1998 Fields medal winner)

Comment: and [this mathoverflow comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389151/elementary-proof-that-an-open-subset-of-bbbrn-does-not-have-measure-zero#comment1149913_389151) by [Terence Tao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Tao) (2006 Fields medal winner).